# from config import get_config

Tags: python, discord.py

i can't import `get_config` from `config`, i don't know why
where is my error and how can i fix it here is a part of my discord bot script

```py
from config import get_config

@bot.command()
async def Ping(ctx, address: str) -> None:
        """
        Performs a HTTP request to the specified address
        :param ctx: commands.Context
        :param address: Address to make request to
        :return: HTTP status code
        """
        if not address.startswith("http"):
            address = f"http://{address}"

        timeout = get_config("timeout")
        address = escape_mentions(address)

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
            timeout=aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=timeout)
        ) as session:
            try:
                async with session.get(address) as res:
                    await ctx.reply(
                        f"Recieved response code: {res.status} ({res.reason})"
                    )
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                await ctx.reply(f"Request timed out after {timeout} seconds")
            except aiohttp.ClientError:
                await ctx.reply(f"Could not establish a connection to {address}")
```

Error: **`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'get_config' is not defined`**

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the correct python module. Try:

```
pip install config
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add the `get_config()` function in your config.py file and also check that you run the code with the correct working directory (where the other file is) that the imports work